# Where to find documentation about systemd-networkd status codes?

Tags: linux, systemd

Background: My package manager seems to have managed to mess up my network daemon so it won't properly manage networks and instead exit with a failure (non-zero) status code. (The particular code is 226/NAMESPACE).

Simply searching for these does not give me any helpful pages at all.

Does anyone know where to find the exit codes for this program, and what this error means in particular?